# Facebook Android SDK always shows web auth dialog instead of native auth dialog / single sign on

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the 3.0 version of the facebook-android-sdk from GitHub in an Android app.

For some reason, when authenticating, the Facebook SDK seems to always show the "web dialog" to enter a username and password manually, rather than using the built in native dialog with single sign on.

When entering the username and password, the app authenticates successfully and everything works, but for some reason SSO never seems to work.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this? No Facebook error messages are called in the log.

Comment: The problem was that I was namespacing the facebook SDK and accidentally changed several class names that should not have been changed in NativeProtocol.java

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not have facebook app in your phone, so android sdk have to use web dialog. Another case is you set the login behavior is SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO, try to change it to SSO_WITH_FALLBACK. For more infomation, have a look at [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/SessionLoginBehavior/)